# Taillight Not Working Even with Bulb Replacement

Tags: electrical, toyota, tail-lights, bulbs

I have a 2004 Toyota Camry, and the taillight is not lighting up when the headlights are turned on.  This is happening equally on both the left and right sides.  When I pulled the old bulb out, I noticed some acid buildup on the end.  We tried cleaning that out as best as we could (it's a small bulb and hard to get into the connector) but still the light will not turn on.

Any idea what the problem could be?  Do I need to replace the whole connector?

Comment: Have you checked the fuse? Does it work with just the parking lights on? Have you checked the connector with a multimeter to see if there is any power there when you turn the lights on?

Comment: Not a multimeter but I did have a basic tester and didn't an indication...  We were trying to check fuses, but didn't see one labeled explicitly.  We did try to check several fuses.

Comment: Make sure the contacts are clean then re-test for a supply. If still not working then check the fuses and the switch.

Comment: Did the problem begin simultaneously on both sides (left and right taillights?)  If so, I would stop looking at the bulbs and their contacts and start troubleshooting at the fusebox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the fuse. If it still good, you will have to check to make sure it has a good ground and that no wires are broken.

Without a multimeter and schematics, its going to be harder to find your issue. By basic tester, do you mean test light?

Comment: Google Image can help with fusebox layouts and help with find where components are located

Comment: FYI; you can edit your own questions and answers, rather than commenting on them to add details.